# Clickable ListView items in Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment

So I created ListView in Fragment. Here's the code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
        //INFLATE THE FRAGMENT LAYOUT FILE
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        //CREATE DATASOURCE
        String[] datasource={"Potisak s klupe",
                "Potisak s klupe bučicama",
                "Potisak s kose klupe",
                "Potisak s kose klupe bučicama",
                "Potisak s kontrakose klupe",
                "Potisak s kontrakose klupe bučicama",
                "Potisak na spravi",
                "Razvlačenja na ravnoj klupi",
                "Razvlačenja na kosoj klupi",
                "Razvlačenja na kontrakosoj klupi",
                "Razvlačenja kablovima na klupi",
                "Propadanja",
                "Sklekovi",
                "Sklekovi s nogama na povišenom",
                "Crossover kablovima",
                "Razvlačenja na leptir mašini",
        };
        //CREATE ADAPTER
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.rowlayout_prsa, R.id.labelrowlayout_prsa_tekst, datasource);
        // BIND ADAPTER TO THE LISTFRAGMENT
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        //RETAIN LISTFRAGMENT INSTANCE ACROSS CONFIGURATION CHANGES
        setRetainInstance(true);
        return rootView;
    }
    // HANDLING ITEM CLICK
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
            TextView txt = (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.labelrowlayout_prsa_tekst);
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), PotisakSKlupe.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        }


}
```

But I can't get to another activity when first list item is clicked with intents. Also tryed with several other methods found on Internet, but no luck. There's no much about fragment list views..

What am I missing here?

Comment: Only first item not able to click?

Comment: All items are not clickable, I'll set them one by one, just don't know how

Answer (score 0):

try this i think u had not called this method in your code.please call and then try.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        TextView txt = (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.labelrowlayout_prsa_tekst);
    l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), PotisakSKlupe.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You just copied my text

Comment: @DaxHr i wrote u had not called this method in which setonClickListener is there . so make a call to this method.

Comment: Getting errors constantly, can you write in code exacly what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

first override this method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

after the onCreateView, onActivityCreated method is called. so put your onListItemClick() inside onActivityCreated method. Now set the list item to be clickable.

```
listView.setClickable(true);
```

and then,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

This might help you.
(Check the variable name that I used and yours.)

Comment: No, NullPointerException :/